# Can anyone shed some light on the random variable which has the following characteristic function?

Tags: probability, characteristic-functions

I have a random variable whose characteristic function is of the form

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}[e^{itX}] = \frac{(1-it)^a}{(1-2it)^{\frac{a}{2}}}\,,
\end{equation}
where $0<a<1$

I am not even sure if this is indeed positive definite, and hence, a characteristic function. If we substitute $e^x \approx (1-x) $, we get $\mathbb{E}[e^{itX}] = 1$, which is the characteristic function of $\delta_0$.

Hence, prima facie, it appears to be the characteristic function of a distribution with most of its mass near 0.

Note that, the characteristic function of a gamma random variable is $(1-it)^{-a}$.

Any information about the distribution will be helpful.

Comment: I did a quick inverse Lapalace Transform check in WolframAlpha and it did not return a closed form result. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=inverse+laplace+transform&a=*C.inverse+laplace+transform-_*Calculator.dflt-&f2=((1-i*t)%5Ea)%2F((1-2*i*t)%5E(a%2F2))&f=InverseLaplaceTransformCalculator.transformfunction%5Cu005f((1-i*t)%5Ea)%2F((1-2*i*t)%5E(a%2F2))&f3=t&f=InverseLaplaceTransformCalculator.variable1%5Cu005ft&f4=x&f=InverseLaplaceTransformCalculator.variable2%5Cu005fx

Comment: Hi, I did the same few minutes back. It does not correspond to any distribution. Sorry for disturbing.